# Spring AOP. BeanCreationException when using @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Try implement AOP in my project but when I use @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true) it's throw BeanCreationException

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <!-- JAVAX CORE -->
    <javax.servlet>3.1.0</javax.servlet>
    <jstl>1.2</jstl>

    <!-- SPRING CORE -->
    <spring.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <spring.securiry>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.securiry>

    <!-- SPRING DATA -->
    <spring-data-jpa>1.10.1.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa>

    <!-- SPRING TEST -->
    <spring.test>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring.test>

    <!-- MultipartResolver -->
    <commons-fileupload>1.3.2</commons-fileupload>

    <!-- POSTGRESQL -->
    <postgre.version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</postgre.version>

    <!-- HIBERNATE -->
    <hb.manager>5.2.5.Final</hb.manager>

    <!-- JUNIT -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

    <!-- LOG4J -->
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- SPRING DATA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING CORE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING AOP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JAVAX CORE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAVAX CORE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- POSTGRESQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgre.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HIBERNATE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hb.manager}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUNIT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING TEST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.test}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MULTIPART RESOLVER -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-fileupload}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ASPECTJ -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
       <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
       <version>1.8.9</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
       <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
       <version>1.8.9</version>
   </dependency>
```

RootConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("biz.project.repository")
@ComponentScan("biz.project")
public class RootConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ControllerExceptionAspect controllerExceptionAspect() {
        return new ControllerExceptionAspect();
    }
//Other beans...
...
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("biz.project")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private SecurityHandler securityHandler;

    /**
     * We register our implementation UserDetailsService,
     * as well as to bring PasswordEncoder password in SHA1 format
     */
    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(getShaPasswordEncoder());
    }

    /**
     * Setting user access rights to the pages of the site.
     *
     * @param httpSecurity HttpSecurity class object to configure the access rights to pages.
     * @throws Exception Exception HttpSecurity class methods.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/content/**").hasAnyRole("CONTENT", "ADMIN")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/unauthorized")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(securityHandler)
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("j_login")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Specify the Spring container, it is necessary to initialize ShaPasswordEncoder
     */
    @Bean
    public ShaPasswordEncoder getShaPasswordEncoder() {
        return new ShaPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

ControllerExceptionAspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
@ComponentScan("biz.project")
public class ControllerExceptionAspect {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ControllerExceptionAspect.class);

    public ControllerExceptionAspect() {
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "exception")
    public void afterThrowingAdvice(Throwable exception) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("*****************************@AfterThrowing***********************************");
        this.logger.error("EXCEPTION IN METHOD -> " + exception.getClass());
    }

}
```

First part of stack trace

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1030)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$2/599850193.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

...
```

Comment: You are trying to intercept all public methods... Which triggers creation of proxies of beans you shouldn't be proxying. Instead of trying to intercept the whole world I suggest limiting it to your own packages.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thanks man! Now it's work.